# How to specify the --target parameter for an ARM embedded system if only output from readelf is available?

Tags: linux, gcc, embedded, arm, cross-compiling

I have an embedded ARM system which runs a Linux with kernel 2.6.20.7. The kernel was compiled with gcc 4.0.2 and I want to compile programs for this system. I have tried several Toolchains (Codesourcery etc.) but no luck. I can compile the program but as soon as I run it on the embedded system I get an "Illegal instruction" error. Now I want to create my own gcc toolchain. First I want to find out the ABI and for which target I have to build my gcc toolchain.

I have downloaded a program from the embedded system and run 'readelf -h':

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            ARM
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8520
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          3772 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x602, has entry point, GNU EABI, software FP, VFP
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         25
  Section header string table index: 24
```

Does someone know how this information can be translated to an --target= Parameter to build a gcc toolchain? It is an ARM system and it runs Linux, so it must be something like --target=arm-linux-..., right? But what comes next?

Comment: Possibly related (for Raspberry Pi which is ARM11 based - but should apply generally): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-build-a-gcc-4-7-toolchain-for-cross-compiling

Comment: Its huge process so my suggestion is 1st try simple hello e.g, cross-compile it with code-sourcery tool chain. but compile as `static` not `dynamic`. e.g arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -static -o hello. if it works then its problem with dynamic libraries